# Exception while processing email invitation : The invited user already exists in the directory

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-graph-sdks

I have the below code written in c#, and using `Micorosoft Graph API`

```
   //Get redemption URL
            var invitation = new Invitation
            {
                InvitedUserEmailAddress = "<email address>",
                InviteRedirectUrl = "<Redirect URL>",
                SendInvitationMessage = false,
            };
            var inviteResponse = graphClient.Invitations
                .Request()
                .AddAsync(invitation).Result;
```

I see following error in the log

> ProcessEmailInvitation - Exception while processing email invitation: One or more errors occurred. (Code: BadRequest
> Message: The invited user already exists in the directory as object ID: xxxxx-xxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx-xxxxxxxxx.

Is it anything to do with `SendInvitationMessage`  parameter?

I tried to change the code as follow,

```
 var inviteResponse = Task.Run(async () => await graphClient.Invitations.Request().AddAsync(invitation).Result);
```

but it says

> Microsoft.Graph.Invition is not awaitable.

Comment: OT: Note that using `.Result()` may cause deadlocks, you should use async/await if possible. You can probably also pass a cancelation token to `AddAsync()`.

Comment: It says Microsoft.Graph.Invition is not awaitable. Could you kindly share some code samples?

Comment: `var inviteResponse = await graphClient.Invitations.Request().AddAsync(invitation);`, the method where you place this call must be async, *i.e.*: `public async Task<ReturnType> SomeMethod(...){...}`, if it's `void` disregard the return type.

Comment: And this is more than likely not related to the problem of the duplicate user. It's just a matter of having a more correct and thus more solid code.

Answer (score 1):

The error indicated that you may invite a user who is already be invited into your tenant, you may test with another email account. And pls allow me to post a sample code here for a better look. If it doesn't help you I'll delete it. By the way `SendInvitationMessage` is `false` by default according to the [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/invitation-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=csharp#request).

```
public async Task<string> inviteUserAsync() {
    var invitation = new Invitation
    {
        InvitedUserEmailAddress = "xxxx@outlook.com",
        InviteRedirectUrl = "https://www.google.com"
    };
    await _graphServiceClient.Invitations.Request().AddAsync(invitation);
    return "success";
}
```

Comment: Can you help what exactly happens when "SendInvitationMessage" is false in Invitation object?

Comment: @kudlatiger according to [api document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/invitation?view=graph-rest-1.0#properties), this property controls `Indicates whether an email should be sent to the user being invited. The default is false.` Per my understanding, we can invite guest users into our tenant in azure portal, and we can reazlize the same feature through this api. Actually I didn't test in my side as I don't have such permission to do this actions.

Comment: Okay. if it is 'false' then what is the point in calling this method! Anyway, it won't send an email. I think something else it does on AAD properties of the user. May be it set "invited' property to 'true' but won't send email.  User can send custom email later. Just guessing